# Was Tomboy removed from Oneiric?

Tags: tomboy, 11.10

Today I installed Oneiric for testing and it works just fine on my machine, without any crashes whatsoever. One thing that bothered me, however, is that Tomboy seems to be missing.

The note taking application used to be default for a long time and even features brilliant Ubuntu One integration, which I use a lot. Was this removed without further notice from the default installation? If yes, why? I never read anything about this on blogs or the planet.

Comment: It's temporary since it doesn't fit on the CD right now.